# Can't get the environment texture to emit light

Tags: lighting

Can't get the environment texture to emit light. I as usual enabled camera, diffused and glossy settings on World Background, set the background color as always to environment texture HDR, but **the object with a non-black diffuse material shows up black unless AO is anabled (in-design render works fine and the object is not excluded from render by being placed in an exluded layer, its ray visibility is also fully on)**. The object is not excluded from rendering, all of its cycles settings are enabled (camera, diffuse, glossy, etc.). Checked nodes for background and composing - all is good. Rendered fine before. Even appended all model's key items into a fresh blender file - to no avail. No clue what's happenning.

Comment: Please post your blend file. If I can play with it I may be able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was that the object was too small in comparison to the standard grid size (how small can it get before the background won't affect it?). When I scaled it up, the background started to emit light as it should. For some reason the grid also looks clipped at the far and near ends like it never had before, though I changed the clipping settings (correctly?) to try to extend the visible range.